# Setting message-ttl doesn't work after update MassTransit to the latest version

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Previously I set TTL for messages globally:

```
MessageDataDefaults.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ttlInSeconds);
```

I was using **8.0.12** and all worked fine. But after updating MassTransit to **8.1.3** I can see that message expiration is not set in RabbitMQ. I still see the usage of `MessageDataDefaults.TimeToLive` in source code of MT but can't understand why it is not set.

Comment: `MessageDataDefaults` have nothing to do with message expiration.

Comment: Currently I am using `IFilter<PublishContext<T>>` and 'IFilter<SendContext<T>>'  to set `context.TimeToLive` for sending and publishing. Is it a correct approach or there is a better one?

Comment: Seems like a good enough approach, yes.